# Starting an app fails

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a node.js app that compiles the runtime version into the `dist` folder.  therefore the `package.json` file specifies the start script `node dist/index.js`.

I now want to containerize it but the container doesn't need to have the distribution directory and those files really should live in the root of the app, thus my `Dockerfile` contains the lines

```
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY dist/* /usr/src/app/
```

which places the runtime files in the image.  the problem I have is that when the docker file issues its last command:

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

it fails because the `index.js` is now in the wrong location (because it's looking for it in the non-existent distribution directory). I could solve the problem by issuing:

```
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

instead but that seems like the wrong thing to do.  what is the correct approach?

*** update I ***

I had modified the `index.js` so it could run from the root of the project (i.e. it expects to find the resources it needs in the `dist/` folder) by issuing a `node dist/index.js`, but of course, this is now also a problem since there is no distribution directory.  how is this generally approached?

Answer (score 2):

I would code all your javascript require calls relative to the current file with no reference to the "dist" directory. So let's say you have `index.js` and `routes.js` in the project root. `index.js` loads routes via `var routes = require('./routes')`. When you compile these, compile BOTH of them into the `dist` directory and all should be well.

If you want to run via `npm start` from the project root, you can configure that to do `node dist/index.js`.

For docker, there's no reason to use npm at all to launch your app. It's an unnecessary process executing for no benefit. Just launch via `node index.js` in your dockerfile with `WORKDIR /usr/src/app`.

Comment: Yes, there is no reason to use `npm start`. Additionally, have a look on `.dockerignore` [1] file which will help you to `COPY` only files that you need.
[1] https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Comment: @PavolPitonak, actually there is.  I've found that environment variables from the `package.json`'s config section don't get loaded unless I run it via the npm start

Comment: Peter, actually, as I indicated to Pavol, I need to use npm start but configuring it to `node dist/index.js` as you suggest doesn't work because when the `index.js` does `express.static('.')` it seeks files in the current directory.  when `npm start` runs, it runs from the root of the project, which means it doesn't find its resources because they are in the `dist/` folder.  within the docker image it _should_ work but in my dev environment it fails

Comment: I also can't define it as `cd dist; node index.js` because when it gets containerized that will fail (since there's no distribution directory)... so I'm thinking the solution is to redefine the start script in the Dockerfile?